# Google Script error -> Invalid email:myuser@mydomain.edu

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

all... new member here...
I manage several Google Apps domains for an EDU. Google sends various email notices about user activities, including suspicious login activities. These notices, are not sent to the users themselves so I want to automate some of them.

The notices contain the username(ID), but not the actual e-mail address.

My team and I have developed a Google script to search for specific messages, extract the username from the message body and then forward a custom support message and the message sent by google.

When we test the script, we get an error: 
***Invalid email: user@mydomain.edu (line 30, "myScript")***.

This error is produced with any username that is obtained via the script:
**var msgTo = userAffected + "@mydomain.edu";**

All user accounts have been verified to exist and be in working order.

If we hard-code the user email address, the script works fine.

I have looked in to unprintable characters, not finding much...

Any ideas?

I have appended the code below:

```
function searchTxt(myTXT) {
//work with labels:
//labelDect and labelProc: labels given to specific messages as they come automatically by the inbox filter/label tool
//the labelDect is removed from the message after it gets processed.
  var labelDect = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("suspicious login detected");
  var labelProc = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("suspicious login processed");
//adminMessage: informational administrative message from domain admin to user.
  var adminMessage = 'Google made us aware that your account might have been hacked.<br/><br/>If you have been contacted about this (or a similar) notice recently, or if you think this is an error, please disregard this message; our duty is to assist you with your account security.<br/><br/>If you suspect that your account was indeed, hacked, please change your password.<br/><br/>You can follow the password change instructions directly from Google or you can contact Jackson State University\'s IT support at (601)-979-0838.<br/><br/>Regards.<br/>';
//signature(+=): include html email admin signature.
  var signature = '<div><div dir="ltr"><div style="text-align:center"><font face="verdana, sans-serif">_______________________________________________________</font></div>';
      signature += '<div style="text-align:center"><font face="verdana, sans-serif"><br></font></div><div style="text-align:center"><font face="verdana, sans-serif"><img src="http://www.somedomain.com"><br>';
//threads: search admin inbox for specific messages.
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:suspicious login detected AND From: "apps-noreply@google.com"');
//Logger: output data to log console/file.
  Logger.log( threads.length.toString() );
 //forwardOptions: forward message options.
  var forwardOptions = {
       from:"domain.admin@domain.edu",
       subject:"Please, review important information about your e-mail account",
       //cc: "domain.admin@domain.edu"
  }

 //outer loop to deal with google email threads
  for ( var currThreadinx = 0; currThreadinx < threads.length; currThreadinx++) {
    var messages = threads[currThreadinx].getMessages();
    //inner loop to deal with messages inside the threads
    for (var msgIndx = 0; msgIndx < messages.length; msgIndx++) {
//email message plain form
        var msgBody = messages[msgIndx].getPlainBody();
//substring delimiters to size the substring to capture the usersid
        var strIndx = msgBody.indexOf('User: ') + String('User: ').length;
        var endIndx = msgBody.indexOf('\n',strIndx);
//actual username
        var userAffected = msgBody.substring(strIndx,endIndx);
//appending the domain to the username
        var msgTo = userAffected + "@domain.edu";
//append all the parts to send the actual message
        forwardOptions.htmlBody = adminMessage + "<br/>" + signature + "<br/><br/>---------- Forwarded message ----------<br/>" + "From: " + messages[msgIndx].getFrom() + "<br/>" + "Date: " + messages[msgIndx].getDate() + "<br/>" + "Subject: " + messages[msgIndx].getSubject() + "<br/><br/>" + messages[msgIndx].getBody();
        messages[msgIndx].forward(msgTo,forwardOptions)
// succesfullll test with hardcoded email address       
    //messages[msgIndx].forward("hard-coded-emailaddress@anotherdomain.com",forwardOptions)
    }
//process labels so that old messages don't get reprocessed.
    labelProc.addToThread(threads[currThreadinx]);
    labelDect.removeFromThread(threads[currThreadinx]);

  }
};
```

Comment: I know you said you've already checked for unprintable characters, but try `Logger.log(encodeURIComponent(msgTo))` right before you send the message. The only `%` you should see in there is a `%40`, which is the @ symbol. Since you said hard-coding an email worked, this code looks fine to me.

Comment: That is a good debugging idea - will try it too.
made progress with trim()
    var userAffected = msgBody.substring(strIndx,endIndx).trim();
so it was unprintables.
Use google script gui to schedule the script; if scheduled to processLabel, I get: processLabel TypeError: Cannot call method "getUnreadCount" of null. (line 30, file "Code"). If scheduled to processInbox, I get: processInbox Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (line 11, file "Code"). I will continue reading..

Thanks for your help, Dan.